# NodeJS connect to SQL Server getaddrinfo ENOTFOUNT

Tags: node.js, sql-server, windows, knex.js

I'm trying to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server using Knex.js, but I'm getting getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND. I'm aware that this is an indication, that NodeJS is unable to resolve the address, often through DNS or protocol problems.

```js
const knex = require('knex')({
    client: 'mssql',
    connection: {
        server: 'filesrv\\docx',  // backslash in string needs to be escaped
        user: 'user',             // changed for privacy reasons
        password: 'secret',       // changed for privacy reasons
        options: {
            port: 1433,
            database: 'DX_Matching_DB'
        }
    }
});
```

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to filesrv\docx:1433 - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND filesrv\docx
>
> at ConnectionError(.\node_modules\tedious\lib\errors.js:13:12)
> at Connection.socketError(.\node_modules\tedious \lib\connection.js:1664:56)
> ...

SQL Server in SQL Server Object Explorer:

[image: SQL Server in SQL Server Object Explorer]

App is run on Windows. Resolve-DnsName is able to resolve filesrv\docx. No change when exchanging filesrv for the corresponding IP.

Comment: Is the `DOCX` instance actually listening on tcp/1433? That port is normally used by the default `MSSQLSERVER` instance. Try removing `port: 1433` from your connection options to see if it correctly resolves the instance name via the SQL Browser service and connects successfully.

Comment: Looking at [the source](https://github.com/knex/knex/blob/master/lib/dialects/mssql/index.js) you could also try `server: 'filesrv'` with `options: { instanceName: 'docx' }`

Comment: The second one did the trick. Thanks. Do you want to post it as an answer too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The knex configuration object uses the instance name inside the options, e.g.:

```js
const knex = require('knex')({
    client: 'mssql',
    connection: {
        server: 'filesrv',
        user: 'user',
        password: 'secret',
        options: {
            database: 'DX_Matching_DB',
            instanceName: 'docx'
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

- You have to setting port in Sql Server Configuration Manager
  - SQL Server Network Configuration -> TCP/IP -> Properties -> IP Address -> Set IP 4 or 6 (example: 1466)

  - Restart Sql Server

> ```
> const knex = require('knex')({
>     client: 'mssql',
>     connection: {
>         server: 'filesrv',
>         user: 'user',
>         password: 'secret',
>         options: {
>             database: 'DX_Matching_DB',
>             instanceName: 'docx',
>             port: 1466
>         }
>     }
> });
> ```