# Knex not able to connection with mssql after upgrade using node

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

I am able to make a successful connection with mssql config with knex version 0.21.16 but when I change knex version to the 2.4.2

I am getting error

**Failed to connect to 12345.dev.abc.com\AV01:1433 - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 12345.dev.abc.com\AV01**

Does anyone face a similar issue like this? I tried to dig out the release documentation of knex but I no luck yet. Also tried to see the examples but everyone does follow the same structure.

"mssql": "9.1.1",
"knex": 2.4.2

**note: I don't need any port number to access the database.**

//config

```
{
    client: 'mssql',
    connection: {
        server: '12345.dev.abc.com\\AV01',
        database: 'DAB70',
        user: 'testsql',
        password: 'testsql',
        sendStringParametersAsUnicode: false,
        requestTimeout: 6000000,
        options: {
            enableArithAbort: true,
            sendStringParametersAsUnicode: false,
            trustServerCertificate: true,

        }
    },
    pool: {
        max: 30
    },

}
```

//db.js

```
let db = knex(config.database)
export default db
//usage
 let result = await db('TEST_TABLE').select(['DATA']).where('ID', ID);
console.log(result);
```

//package.json

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "main": "src/app.js",
    "description": "",
    "version": "0.7.4",
    "private": false,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "babel-node src/app.js",
        "start-debug": "babel-node %NODE_DEBUG_OPTION% src/app.js",
    },
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": ""
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": "16.x"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-cli": "6.26.0",
        "babel-eslint": "8.2.1",
        "babel-plugin-root-import": "6.6.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "6.24.1",
        "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring": "6.23.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "6.26.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "6.23.0",
        "babel-polyfill": "6.26.0",
        "babel-preset-env": "1.7.0",
        "babel-register": "6.26.0",
        "babel-resolver": "1.1.0",
        "eslint": "8.37.0",
        "eslint-config-standard": "17.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-html": "7.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "2.27.5",
        "eslint-plugin-node": "11.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-promise": "6.1.1",
        "eslint-plugin-standard": "4.1.0",
        "nyc": "15.1.0",
        "should": "13.2.3",
        "sinon": "15.0.3",
        "standard-version": "9.5.0",
        "supertest": "6.3.3",
        "transform-runtime": "0.0.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@hapi/hapi": "21.3.1",
        "@hapi/inert": "7.1.0",
        "@hapi/vision": "7.0.1",
        "aguid": "2.0.0",
        "babel-cli": "6.26.0",
        "babel-eslint": "8.2.1",
        "babel-polyfill": "6.26.0",
        "babel-preset-env": "1.7.0",
        "babel-register": "6.26.0",
        "babel-resolver": "1.1.0",
        "bookshelf": "1.2.0",
        "bookshelf-default-select": "1.0.4",
        "bookshelf-eloquent": "0.1.15",
        "bookshelf-modelbase": "2.11.0",
        "bookshelf-uuid": "1.0.1",
        "boom": "7.2.0",
        "cfenv": "1.2.4",
        "es6-promisify": "7.0.0",
        "fast-json-patch": "3.1.1",
        "ftp": "0.3.10",
        "hapi-api-version": "2.3.1",
        "hapi-auth-basic": "5.0.0",
        "hapi-auth-cookie-jwt": "3.0.1",
        "hapi-auth-jwt2": "10.4.0",
        "hapi-server-session": "5.1.2",
        "hapi-swagger": "16.0.1",
        "inert": "5.1.0",
        "javascript-state-machine": "3.1.0",
        "joi": "17.9.1",
        "joi-date-extensions": "1.1.1",
        "joi-to-json-schema": "5.1.0",
        "joi-to-swagger": "6.2.0",
        "json_merger": "1.2.0",
        "jsonwebtoken": "9.0.0",
        "knex": "2.4.2",
        "log4js": "6.9.1",
        "mssql": "9.1.1",
        "node-cache": "5.1.2",
        "node-cron": "3.0.2",
        "node-schedule": "2.1.1",
        "node-stringify": "0.2.1",
        "nodemailer": "6.9.1",
        "nodemailer-shared": "2.0.0",
        "object-hash": "3.0.0",
        "openid-client": "5.4.0",
        "request": "2.88.2",
        "request-promise": "4.2.2",
        "tedious": "15.1.3",
        "unidecode": "0.1.8",
        "vertica": "0.5.5",
        "vision": "5.3.1",
        "yar": "9.0.1"
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NodeJS connect to SQL Server getaddrinfo ENOTFOUNT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69372182/nodejs-connect-to-sql-server-getaddrinfo-enotfount)

Comment: Thanks @Matt for suggestion. I tried this answer but it is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same isue. The config that worked for me:

```
{
    client: 'mssql',
    connection: {
        server: '12345.dev.abc.com',
        user: 'user',
        password: 'password',
        port: 1433,
        stream: false,
        options: {
            database: 'DAB70',
            enableArithAbort: true,
            encrypt: true,
            instanceName: 'AV01',
            trustServerCertificate: true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can omit port if you don't need it